# Change property of multiple image button

Tags: android, loops

My activity has 9 image buttons, I would like to change certain properties of multiple image buttons like disable all the image buttons in a certain situation & then enable them back. I think may be i can use loop something like this....

```
// int [] ids = { R.id.imgBtn1, R.id.imgBtn2......, R.id.imgBtn9 };
// for (int i=0; i<=ids.length; i++){
// ids[i].setEnabled(true);
// }
```

Thank you all

Comment: pull all views in one list and use that

Comment: @shayanpourvatan could you please give an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Add views from array of ids
ArrayList<View> views = new ArrayList<>();
int [] ids = { R.id.imgBtn1, R.id.imgBtn2, R.id.imgBtn9 };
for (int i=0; i<ids.length; ++i){
    views.add(findViewById(ids[i]));
}

// Loop each view and enable it
for (View view : views) {
    view.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: @user2551070 I think `i<=ids.length` return `ArryIndexOutOfBound`, am I right ? I think you need use `i<ids.length`

Comment: @shayanpourvatan correct. Copy-paste error from OPs code.

Comment: Thank you exactly what I was looking for . This approach is more flexible. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

define one list like follow:

```
List<ImageView> images = new ArrayList<>();

ImageView iv1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1);
ImageView iv2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image2);
ImageView iv3 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image3);
ImageView iv4 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image4);
ImageView iv5 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image5);
ImageView iv6 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image6);
ImageView iv7 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image7);
//.....
```

and put all in one list,

```
images.add(iv1);
images.add(iv2);
// add other view
```

then work with this list and do what you want like:

```
for (ImageView iv : images)
{
  // your code
}
```

Comment: Thank you I tried you method too, it's working. But the marked answer is more suitable to my needs. Anyway thanks for your help.